# app crashes while opening main Activity because of getString(R.string.xxx)

Tags: android, kotlin, crash

I am working in app with two languages

in autocomplatetextview i want to change values according to the language of device

i try this code

```
var EGP = getString(R.string.egyptian_pound_egp)
    var USD = getString(R.string.american_dollar_usd)
    var SAR = getString(R.string.Saudia_Ryal)
    var KWD = getString(R.string.Kuwaiti_Dinar)
```

and full code of MainActivity

```
package com.example.currency

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.widget.Adapter
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
    import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView
    import android.widget.Button
    import androidx.annotation.StringRes
    import androidx.core.widget.addTextChangedListener
    import com.google.android.material.internal.ContextUtils.getActivity
    import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        var EGP = getString(R.string.egyptian_pound_egp)
        var USD = getString(R.string.american_dollar_usd)
        var SAR = getString(R.string.Saudia_Ryal)
        var KWD = getString(R.string.Kuwaiti_Dinar)
    
        lateinit var convertButton: Button
        lateinit var amount: TextInputEditText
        lateinit var result: TextInputEditText
        lateinit var from: AutoCompleteTextView
        lateinit var to: AutoCompleteTextView
    
        val listValue = mapOf(
            USD to 0.052356,
            EGP to 1.0,
            SAR to 0.197040,
            KWD to 0.0166838
        )
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            initalizeViews()
            populateMenu()
    
    
            convertButton.setOnClickListener {
    
                calcResault()
            }
            amount.addTextChangedListener {
                calcResault()
            }
        }
    
        private fun initalizeViews() {
            convertButton = findViewById(R.id.button)
            amount = findViewById(R.id.AmountTIET)
            result = findViewById(R.id.ResultTIET)
            from = findViewById(R.id.FromACTV)
            to = findViewById(R.id.ToACTV)
    
    
    
        }
    
        private fun populateMenu() {
            val currencyList = listOf(EGP, USD, SAR, KWD)
            val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_currency, currencyList)
            from.setAdapter(adapter)
            to.setAdapter(adapter)
    
    
        }
    
        private fun calcResault(){
            if (amount.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
                result.setText(
                    String.format(
                        "%.2f", listValue.get(to.text.toString())!!.times(
                            amount.text.toString().toDouble()
                                .div(listValue.get(from.text.toString())!!)
                        )
                    )
                )
            } else {
                amount.setError(getString(R.string.amount_required))
            }
        }
    
    
    }
```

after testing some codes , i found that getString(R.string.xxx) the reason of the crashing

when change getString(R.string.xxx) with string value the app opening with no problem

but i  want to change values according to the language of device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getString` requires your `Activity` to have a `Context`, and at construction time **it doesn't have one**. So when you define those top-level variables that are initialised at construction time, your `getString` calls fail. The error log will tell you this, that you're trying to do something with a *null* `Context` or similar.

The context shows up somewhere around `onCreate`, so if you can guarantee those values won't be used until the Activity is `CREATED` (i.e. you won't be reading them until `onCreate` or later) then you could use a `lazy` delegate. That only initialises them when they're first read - so if you're reading them when the `Activity` has its `Context`, the `getString` call works fine!

```
val EGP = by lazy { getString(R.string.egyptian_pound_egp) }
val USD = by lazy { getString(R.string.american_dollar_usd) }
val SAR = by lazy { getString(R.string.Saudia_Ryal) }
val KWD = by lazy { getString(R.string.Kuwaiti_Dinar) }
```

But the problem here is you're not first reading these in `onCreate` or later - it happens in the next line where you build a `Map` using those values, which is another top-level variable that's initialised at construction. So you don't get the benefit of the `lazy` because it's called too early.

You can fix this by making that map `lazy` too:

```
val listValue by lazy { mapOf(
    USD to 0.052356,
    EGP to 1.0,
    SAR to 0.197040,
    KWD to 0.0166838
)}
```

Now `listValue` won't be initialised until it's read either! So it won't try to read those other values until it's actually accessed - so same deal, as long as `listValue` isn't read by something before `onCreate`, it should be fine.

This is the kind of thing you have to watch out for with `lazy` delegates in Android lifecycle components like `Activity` and `Fragment`, or anywhere you need lazy initialisation really. Make sure it's not being read too early by something else, and make those lazy too if appropriate.

---

Using lazy delegates requires your variables to be `val`s though - if you need to be able to change them, make them `lateinit` instead and initialise them manually as soon as you can. You could keep `listValue` as a `lazy` if you want, just make sure the `lateinit var`s it initialises from are assigned before it's accessed

Answer (score 0):

Make those be either `lateinit var` or use `by lazy {}` to defer initialization. You cannot call `getString()` until after `super.onCreate()` has been called in your `onCreate()` function.

Comment: still crashing after use  lateinit var EGP: String
    and call getStrinf after super.onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

(**CAUTION**: You values will be re-initialized every time `onCreate()` method called)

```
lateinit var EGP: String
lateinit var USD: String
lateinit var listValues: Map<String, Double>
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    EGP = getString(R.string.egyptian_pound_egp)
    USD = getString(R.string.american_dollar_usd)

    listValues = mapOf(
        USD to 0.052356,
        EGP to 1.0
    )

  //Rest of your code  
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).